# "I want to tell you" or "I want you to tell"?

Tags: word-choice

If I want tell about something to somebody, which phrase is correct:
"I want to tell you" or "I want you to tell"?

Comment: Minor note: it’s spelled *phrase*, because English spelling is psychotic.

Answer (score 2):

*"I want to tell you"* is a statement of intent. It means I have something to say, and I want to say/give it to you, I will say it and you will hear/read it.

*"I want you to tell me "* is a request, a desire, you know something I do not, and I want to know it. I will read/hear it, and you will speak it

For example:

> **You**: "I want you to tell me the answer to my question"
>
> **Me**: "I want to
>   tell you the answer!"

Keep in mind, that they can be used as negatives e.g.

> I want to tell you, but I can not

Answer (score 1):

" I want to tell you" means that I will speak and you will listen.

"I want you to tell (me)" means that you will speak and I will listen.

Comment: Thanks, I knew that. I needed confirmation for the teacher. She persistently corrects me.